# How do I restrict pipelines to specific branches without using triggers?

Tags: azure-devops

How can I restrict on-demand (i.e. not triggered) pipelines in Azure DevOps so that they only run on specific branches?

For instance, I have a pipeline (using the newer YAML syntax) that should only run on the `master` branch, as it is used to push code through to production, and can only be run by certain developers (we handle a lot of PII data, so our audit controls are fairly demanding). I have another pipeline that should run on any branch *except* `master`, as it is used to push code through to integration/testing environments, and can be run by anyone.

If I specified a trigger, I can tell it only to fire on certain branches; but if I set `trigger: none` in my YAML then I can't apply those restrictions. Any ideas?

Comment: This thread might give you some ideas, although it doesn't seem to be supported out of the box: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59263643/how-to-remove-lock-branch-selection-when-queuing-new-azure-devops-pipeline

Comment: Following the comment above me (that you should take a look at my answer there...) I have another idea, you can remove the yaml file from the branch you do not want it to run from..

Comment: Thanks @ShaykiAbramczyk , I think your code snippet in the linked answer is the best solution for now, so I'll run with that. I'm not keen on deleting the YAML file from branches I don't want the build to run on, because otherwise that deletion will propagate on to branches I do want it to run on if I'm not very careful when merging (or someone else merges without knowing about it)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, I just went with the trigger approach; you typically won't be merging code back to `master` unless you're wanting to deploy it somewhere (hopefully to production).

Answer (score 8):

I came across this thread because I had the same requirement. In my case I wanted to restrict the pipeline to *releases/** branches.
In case that helps, what I did is to put a condition on the stage :

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - releases/*

...

- name: isReleasesBranch
  value: $[startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'releases/')]

...

stages:
- stage: Production
  displayName: 'Production Deploy'
  dependsOn: QA
  condition: and(succeeded(), or(variables.isReleasesBranch))

...
```

Comment: I'd suggest one change to this solution; maybe adding a powershell task which checks the isReleaseBranch variable, and explicitly fails the pipeline if it is not valid. That way, the person running the pipeline from the wrong branch gets direct feedback of what was wrong.

Comment: "include: - releases/*" means pipeline will run only when the changes is merging to release branches, why do we need isReleasesBranch?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I think it was to prevent deploying to production a non release branch in case the pipeline was triggered manually by someone.

Comment: I want the opposite of this. How can I restrict my pipeline to only branch FROM releases/*.

Comment: Of course anyone could just take that restriction out of the pipeline in their own branch, and trigger it from there manually.
It still is useful for preventing accidents